# Find the remainder $4444^{4444}$ when divided by 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the remainder $4444^{4444}$ when divided by 9

When a number is divisible by 9 the possible remainder are $0, 1, 2,3, 4,5,6,7,8$ we know that $0$ is not a possible answer. My friend told me the answer is $7$ but how

I am thinking of taking 4444 divide by 9 and that left a remainder of 7 so $4444 \cong 7$ mod 9 based on that I am guessing $4444^{4444} \cong 7^{4444}$ mod 9 so to me no matter how big the power is that will still be a remainder of 7 is that correct to think like that

Comment: You're on the right track.  Have you learned any shortcuts to computing residues for large powers?  (I'm thinking of one that involves expressing the exponent in binary.)

Comment: no unfortunately that is all i know

Comment: @user146269 Look at $7, 7^2, 7^3, 7^4, \ldots$ mod $9$ and see if you can find a pattern.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You've got the right idea! Notice now that $7 \cong -2 \pmod 9$ and $(-2)^3 \cong -8 \cong 1 \pmod 9$. Using this can you write $4444$ as a multiple of a certain (useful) number plus a remainder term?

**Extra:** An example for clarification. What's the remainder on dividing $33^{33}$ by $7$? We have: $$33 \cong 5  \pmod 7$$ so $$33^{33} \cong 5^{33} \pmod 7$$
But now we can notice that $5^3 \cong -1 \cong 6\pmod 7$ and therefore: 
$$33^{33} \cong 5^{33} \cong 5^{3 \times 11} \cong (5^3)^{11} \cong (-1)^{11} \cong -1 \cong 6\pmod 7$$ 
So $33^{33}$ has remainder $6$ on division by $7$.
Can you try a similar thing with your example?

Comment: Feel free to ask for more hints/clarification if you need it :)

Comment: i do not quite follow it is because i know that $4444 \cong 7$ mod 9 that is why i was able to derive that. elaborate more in the hint

Comment: I'll add a simpler example to my answer.

Comment: after i follow your example i have (-2)^1111 mod 9 how do i simplify this

Comment: Sounds good to me, now notice that $1111 = (3 \times 370) + 1$, so now....?

Comment: i know that $7^4 \cong  7 \cong (-2)$ mod 9 so $7^{4444} \cong 7^{4 \dot 1111} \cong (-2)^{1111}$ then i don't see how this reduces to just $(-2)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29649/discussion-between-zestylemonzi-and-user146269).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) ( $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod m$) you can write:
$$ 4444^{4444}\equiv 4444^{6\cdot 740+4}\equiv 4444^4\equiv 7^4\equiv 25\equiv 7\pmod 9$$

Comment: yeah unfortunately i can not use it. A friend of mine was telling me about it. thanks though

Comment: Please do not skip the step of checking if $a$ is coprime to $9$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You may now want to have a look at [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Comment: this is not helping me getting anywhere